# After saving the data to the database once, it does not save the second one

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, async-await

I'm pretty new to this industry.

This is the Create method in BaseRepository:

```
    public async Task CreateAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        await _db.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

This is the Create method inside the UserService class.

```
    public  ResultService<UserCreateDTO> Create(UserCreateVM userCreateVM)
    {
        ResultService<UserCreateDTO> result = new ResultService<UserCreateDTO>();

        UserCreateDTO createDto = _mapper.Map<UserCreateDTO>(userCreateVM);
        User newUser = _mapper.Map<User>(createDto);
        var addedUser =  _userRepo.CreateAsync(newUser);

        if (addedUser != null)
        {
            result.Data = createDto;
        }
        else
        {
            result.AddError(ErrorType.BadRequest, "Ekleme işlemi başarısız");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is our Post method in the API:

```
    // POST api/<UserController>
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserCreateDTO>> Post([FromBody] UserCreateDTO userDTO, int id)
    {
        if(userDTO == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var user = new User
        {
            ImagePath = userDTO.ImagePath,
            FirstName = userDTO.FirstName,
            LastName = userDTO.LastName,
            SecondLastName = userDTO.SecondLastName,
            BirthDate = userDTO.BirthDate,
            BirthPlace = userDTO.BirthPlace,
            TcNo = userDTO.TcNo,
            DateOfStart = DateTime.Now,
            DateOfExit = userDTO.DateOfExit,
            CompanyName = userDTO.CompanyName,
            JobName = userDTO.JobName,
            Department = userDTO.Department,
            Address = userDTO.Address,
            IsActive = userDTO.IsActive,
            Role = userDTO.Role,
            PhoneNumber=userDTO.PhoneNumber,
            Email = userDTO.Email,
            NormalizedEmail = userDTO.NormalizedEmail.ToUpper(),
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Password = userDTO.Password,
            UserName=userDTO.Username,
            NormalizedUserName=userDTO.NormalizedUsername.ToUpper(),
        };

        UserCreateVM userCreateVM = new UserCreateVM()
        {
            ImagePath = user.ImagePath,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            SecondLastName= user.SecondLastName,
            BirthDate = user.BirthDate,
            BirthPlace = user.BirthPlace,
            TcNo = user.TcNo,
            DateOfStart = DateTime.Now,
            DateOfExit= user.DateOfExit,
            CompanyName = user.CompanyName,
            JobName = user.JobName,
            Department = user.Department,
            Address = user.Address,
            IsActive = user.IsActive,
            Role = user.Role,
            PhoneNumber = userDTO.PhoneNumber,
            Email = user.Email.ToUpper(),
            NormalizedEmail= user.NormalizedEmail,
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Password = user.Password,
            Username = user.UserName,
            NormalizedUsername=user.NormalizedUserName.ToUpper()
            
        };


        var createdUser =  _userService.Create(userCreateVM);

        if(createdUser != null)
        {
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = userDTO.Id }, createdUser);
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

As a result of these methods, after saving the user's data to the database once, it does not perform another save operation, but it appears as if it has been saved in Swagger. I would greatly appreciate it if someone who knows the reason could write about it. I apologize for my English being a bit bad.

I tried to make the `Create` method in the `UserService` asynchronous, but I encountered an error on the line `var addedUser = _userRepo.CreateAsync(newUser);`. After fixing the error, I reverted the method back to its original state because I was getting a 500 error in Swagger.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment you have an issue on the following line:

```cs
var addedUser =  _userRepo.CreateAsync(newUser);
```

The method `CreateAsync` returns a task, that is an object that holds information about an asynchronous operation. In your current code, you only check if you get a task back (which you always will) but don't wait for the task to finish.

It's best that you rewrite your method as follows:

```cs
public async Task<ResultService<UserCreateDTO>> Create(UserCreateVM userCreateVM)
{
    ResultService<UserCreateDTO> result = new ResultService<UserCreateDTO>();

    UserCreateDTO createDto = _mapper.Map<UserCreateDTO>(userCreateVM);
    User newUser = _mapper.Map<User>(createDto);

    try
    {
        await _userRepo.CreateAsync(newUser);
        result.Data = createDto;
    }
    catch
    {
        result.AddError(ErrorType.BadRequest, "Ekleme işlemi başarısız");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here you see that I wait for the result of the `CreateAsync` before setting the result and returning it. I have also wrapped it in a try-catch so you know when the `CreateAsync` method has thrown an error. Here I have used a global catch where I catch all the errors (also called Pokemon catching, gotta catch 'em all ) which is advised against. Only catch errors that you know will happen and catch those.

This also means that you need to change the following line in the `Post` to this:

```cs
var createdUser = await _userService.Create(userCreateVM);
```

I would suggest to look further into how the async and await works in C#.